# Nuxt.js server side Javascript issue, framework confusion

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vue.js, nuxt.js, web-development-server

A partner and I are working on website for a school project, and we have decided to use Vue.js and Nuxt.js as the front-end frameworks, and Vuesax as a UI Framework. Neither of us have any experience with these frameworks or frankly web development until recently. We ran into our first major issue when we were trying to create a profile drop down menu, where the items of the menu become visible when you click the profile avatar, however when trying to use the event listener, we realized Nuxt.js (based on node) was meant for universal javascript rather then strictly client side, so when we use "document.getElementId" for event handling, it says that it is not defined. (no DOM)

[image: error message]
We really don't know what to do from here - find a new framework or plug-in/extension - and we are wondering if we could get some insight. We want to be able to use Javascript purely to handle frontend events. Moving forward, we also want to fetch information from a database (currently in MySQL but may change due to feedback), and we were thinking of using Spring Boot as our backend framework, as it allows us to handle requests, create servlets in Java(our most comfortable language)and also has Tomcat.

We have done a lot of research and consulted a lot of websites and acquaintances, but sometimes it is difficult to find things that pertain to something so specific, in this case our project. We are also having trouble finding a system of frameworks that is cohesive and compatible with each other. We are more than willing to learn, so any insight, feedback or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Nuxt has components such as [client-only](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/) that can be used to execute code only in the client side. That being said, usually with Vue you wouldn't be usually interacting with the DOM directly. Your question too broad as it could be a number of issues. Instead try posting the code you are trying to execute and where/when you are executing it.

Comment: Also `window` and `document` should be available in lifecycle hooks https://nuxtjs.org/guides/concepts/server-side-rendering#server-vs-browser-environments

Comment: That you use `getElementId` raw DOM with a framework and don't know if you do it right strongly suggests that you're doing it not in the way that it was intended by the framework. Consider addressing this first. *was meant for server-side javascript rather then strictly client side* - no, it was meant for universal JS, i.e. it renders on both server and client side. Use guards for conditional client- and server-only code - `if`s and lifecycles. E.g. `mount` is ignored on server. See https://nuxtjs.org/guides/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/ . What was your motivation for Nuxt? You may or not need it.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks for your response! I downloaded the "client-only" component and put it to use, but when I tried again, I get the same error; i've pasted the image in my original question

Comment: @EstusFlask That was my mistake, sorry for the bad wording! Yes, it is universal js, but we thought that the server side rendering was causing the issue after doing some searching (may be wrong though). Our motivation for using Nuxt was just so we could easily make and run a project in a few steps with all the dependencies and files already installed for us; the Vuesax documentation also recommended we use those frameworks together. As beginners, it seemed like a quick, easy, and good option for us, but other than that, there's no other reason why we used it

Comment: According to your description, you intend on building your front end dom manipulation with vanilla js as such it would be almost impossible to use most front end frameworks you would rather use vanilla js all the way in the case in my opinion. For fetching data you could use vanilla as well.

Comment: Secondly, if you intend to learn Vue and nuxt during your development process you'll need to use Vues method of doing things and look into the nuxt and Vue docs. [Document not defined reason](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/).

Comment: Nuxt major benefits are simplified component state hydration in server-side hooks, universal client/server router,  SEO friendliness because of dynamic server pages, ability to generate static pages, improve client render time at the expense of server. If this is not important, you don't need Nuxt, it's just a third-party Vue-based framework with its own rules. Better stick to vanilla Vue (Vue CLI project). Server side in a lang of your choice, if you're after SPA it should be REST API.  Also such questions aren't suited for SO, try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ next time.

Answer (score 1):

From the image, you are trying to perform dom manipulation in nuxt and both windows and document are not defined.

To do what you're trying to do you have to try it like this.

```
<template>
  // @click is the event listener to change the state
  <button @click="mobileNavOpen = !mobileNavOpen">Toggle btn</button>
  // bind the show class conditonally according to mobileNaveOpen state and add the display state to the show class.
  <div :class="{show : mobileNavOpen}">
    <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <nuxt-link class="nav-link" to="/">
          Home
        </nuxt-link>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <nuxt-link class="nav-link" to="/about">
          About
       </nuxt-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
 export default {
    data() {
      return {
        mobileNavOpen: false,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      closeMobileNavbar() {
        this.mobileNavOpen = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```